# Как из String'ga вытащить различные аргументы?

Tags: java

Как из строки получить определенные аргументы?

Вот, что мне нужно:

```
String s = "arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4";
System.out.printIn("Аргумент в строчке s = " s.getArg(4));
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: String[] args = s.split(" ");   System.out.printIn("Аргумент в строчке s = " + args[3]);

Comment: Если вы в вопросах будете помещать свой код, а не ссылки на посторонние ресурсы, шансы получить ответ будут выше.